# How to destroy session outside of Codeigniter folder

Tags: codeigniter

I am working on CI project.
**Here is a scenario :**

There is a project A ( folder A ), inside A there are many different portal say B ,C, D,E etc. 
When I need to logout from C then it should be logout from B also and vice-versa.
Similarly, if we don't want to logout from D , then how to handle such situation. Currently, I am stuck in this situation.

In reality, in my case project A contain 8 portal. Even If I am routing to logout page of each portal then also it is not working.

I have tried by deleting default cookie of the CI but not working in any case.
My helper, which is used to check user logged in or not:

```
if ( ! function_exists('_is_frontuser_login')){
    function _is_frontuser_login($thi){
        $userid = $thi->session->userdata('userid');
        //  echo $userid;die();
        //$usertype = $thi->session->userdata('user_type');
        if(isset($userid) && $userid!=""){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }   
}
```

logout page contain this set of code:-

```
public function adslogout(){
    $this->session->sess_destroy();
    redirect("User/index");
}
```

I have discuss this with many developer they give me suggestion to make changes in session.php. I have tried but didn't get success.

Please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is your solution not to keep the sessionID but create a per-portal token table. That way if you want to logout of Portal A then remove the token attached to that sessonID and Portal A. Equally if you should automatically logout of Portal C at the same time you can do this. Effectively you create one session but have tokens attached which relate to different portals.

Answer (score 0):

**Try to create a session for each portal for every successful log in like:**

```
$this->session->set_userdata('portal_A',$loggedinCredentials);
$this->session->set_userdata('portal_B',$loggedinCredentials);
$this->session->set_userdata('portal_C',$loggedinCredentials);
```

Then **unset** the corresponding session if they log out on a portal like:

```
   $this->session->unset_userdata('portal_C');
```

then on every access of portal you just have to use **isset()** check if the portal session is existing.

read : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html?highlight=session#